# Xlsx file being created from javascript does not open in Windows MS-Office

Tags: javascript, xml, xlsx

```
var a = window.document.createElement('a');
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([excel_content], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'}));
            a.download = 'REPORT'+'.xlsx';
            // Append anchor to body.
            document.body.appendChild(a)
            a.click();
```

The above code works when I open the downloaded file in LibreOffice (Linux), but the same does not work in Windows MS-Office.
The contents of my file is xml elements which I'm trying to save it as xlsx format.
But only MS-Office shows following error

```
The file you're trying to open is a different format as specified bythe file extension"
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have your contents of file into .csv format to be able to open into MS-Office.

There are lot's of plugin available although this is the sample code you can try out..

this will convert your JSON data to excel file...

```
function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {
//If JSONData is not an object then JSON.parse will parse the JSON string in an Object
var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

var CSV = '';
//Set Report title in first row or line

CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';

//This condition will generate the Label/Header
if (ShowLabel) {
    var row = "";

    //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
    for (var index in arrData[0]) {

        //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
        row += index + ',';
    }

    row = row.slice(0, -1);

    //append Label row with line break
    CSV += row + '\r\n';
}

//1st loop is to extract each row
for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
    var row = "";

    //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
    for (var index in arrData[i]) {
        if (index == 'Date_Time') {
            var dateString = arrData[i][index].substr(6);
            var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
            var hours = ('0' + (currentTime.getHours())).slice(-2)
            var min = ('0' + (currentTime.getMinutes())).slice(-2)
            var sec = ('0' + (currentTime.getSeconds())).slice(-2)
            var date = currentTime.toDateString() + " " + hours + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
            row += '"' + date + '",';
        } else {
            row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
        }
    }

    row.slice(0, row.length - 1);

    //add a line break after each row
    CSV += row + '\r\n';
}

if (CSV == '') {
    alert("Invalid data");
    return;
}

//Generate a file name
var fileName = "MyReport_";
//this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g, "_");

//Initialize file format you want csv or xls
var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

// Now the little tricky part.
// you can use either>> window.open(uri);
// but this will not work in some browsers
// or you will not get the correct file extension    

//this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = uri;

//set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
link.style = "visibility:hidden";
link.download = fileName + ".csv";

//this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, I'm using the concept of xml to create an xlsx file. Since in xml we can set any styles to any cell that will reflect in xlsx and that was my requirement. And I'm just changing the format of my whole xml string to xlsx.
I have no problem using any other library but I cannot design the Excel as per my client's requirements with that library